# Печать документа

Tags: php, javascript

Есть проект на php+js+mysql. У каждого пользователя системы есть личные шаблоны для печати, отличающиеся шапками, заголовками и т.д. и в форме есть табличная часть.
Общие шаблоны должны хранится на сервере, чтобы любой пользователь мог зайти скачать их и изменить (к примеру шапку), а после добавить в свои личные шаблоны. Также в проекте есть "документы", на основании которых необходимо производить печать по сформированному шаблону пользователя. Каким образом лучше всего реализовать данный алгоритм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаблон будет представлять собой HTML-документ с *"маркерами"* - специальными метками, которые будут заменяться на результат выполнения скрипта. Например,

```
##table()##
```

Этот маркет будет заменён на табличную часть. Хранить шаблоны в папке пользователя.